# Input checkbox checked changed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the checkbox hack to make a menu and when it is checked I want to give an element a background color.

Specifically the top-bar id.

```
function checked() {

    if (document.getElementById('site-nav-toggle').checked) {
        document.getElementById('top-bar').style.background = "#333";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('top-bar').style.background = "none"; 
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/faooful/Dp7wR/

Comment: ... and the question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your code

1. You need to make sure the function is defined first. (Change the second drop-down in the top-left to `No wrap - in <head>`)
2. `checked` is a keyword in that context. Try renaming the function

Here is an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dp7wR/4/

Answer (score 0):

Changed your function name, "checked" is already a property on the input so onclick="clicked()" tries to used the clicked attribute rather than your method.  Give it a meaningful name and it'll actually call your method.